# Powershell Script to Export all Devices in Device Manager as tree or list?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, device-manager

With former Windows versions, it was possible to print the information from the Device Manager, but it does not seem possible to do this with Windows 7 any longer.

I am looking for a Powershell script that exports all devices that also appear in Device Manager to a text file, and optionally creating it in a tree-like Device Manager type of view if possible.

This would be so helpful in many cases, but I haven't found anything like this from what research I've done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Powershell Script to export all Devices in Device Manager**
>
> I am looking for a Powershell script that exports all devices that
>   also appear in Device Manager to a text file, and optionally creating
>   it in a tree-like Device Manager type of view if possible.

I just tested this with Windows 7 and it seems to work just fine from what I could tell, so here's a PowerShell module you can import and then use to get the device detail you need plus some.

An example syntax below as well to put to a text file which you requested. Just plug in your syntax and then put the `| Out-File -Append -Force "C:\path\FileListName.txt"` command to the end of it with your file location to put in a text file for later review (*http://ss64.com/ps/out-file.html*).

**EXAMPLE**

```
Get-Device | Sort-Object -Property Name | ft Name, DriverVersion, DriverProvider, IsPresent, HasProblem -AutoSize | Out-File -Append -Force "C:\path\FileListName.txt"
```

**Import-Module Note**

If you have trouble with the import, just download the ZIP file, extract or copy the `Release` folder from within it to your desktop temporarily, and then use the explicit path import syntax to point to the psd1 file:
`Import-Module C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\Release\DeviceManagement.psd1 –Verbose`

---

**Source Links:**

- *https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Device-Management-7fad2388*
- *http://blogs.technet.com/b/wincat/archive/2012/09/06/device-management-powershell-cmdlets-sample-an-introduction.aspx*

> **Downloading and using the Device Management PowerShell Cmdlets**
>
> The Device Management PowerShell cmdlets are available at:
>   http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Device-Management-7fad2388
>
> To download, follow the above link and click on the “Download” button.
>   Save and extract the contents of the.zip file to a folder of your
>   choice.
>
> The next step is to import the module and start using the cmdlets! In
>   order to do so, launch an instance of PowerShell and follow the below
>   steps:
>
> **Importing the Cmdlet module:**
>
> Import-Module .\PSCmdlet.psd1 –Verbose
>
> **Listing Devices**
>
> All devices present on the system
>
> Get-Device | Sort-Object -Property Name | ft Name, DriverVersion,
>   DriverProvider, IsPresent, HasProblem -AutoSize
>
> “Hidden” devices
>
> Get-Device -ControlOptions DIGCF_ALLCLASSES | Sort-Object -Property
>   Name | Where-Object -Property IsPresent -eq $false | ft Name,
>   DriverVersion, DriverProvider, IsPresent, HasProblem -AutoSize
>
> Disabled devices
>
> Get-Device | Sort-Object -Property Name | Where-Object -Property
>   ConfigurationFlags -Like '*DISABLED*' | ft Name, InstanceId -AutoSize

Comment: Note, that according to the article `Get-Device` requires `Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8` and OP is using `Windows 7`. I wish that I could trust specs without testing them.

Comment: I noticed that too; however, I tested and confirmed that it ALSO works with Windows 7 which I did indicate in my answer specifically. I did NOT post an answer until I tested and confirmed all worked as expected with Windows 7 as I usually do as a standard per the wording of the request for any or all parts of it to satisfy accordingly.

Comment: Get-Device is not available in Windows 10? Tested as administrator in Windows Powershell and PowerShell (Core). Would also like to export driver versions and names

Answer (score 7):

You still can [print/export from MsInfo32](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-can-you-print-a-device-manager-report-in/1a309ccf-2f64-481a-9e3e-b16034618b83):

> There is no such option to print the Device Manager Report in Windows
>   7 as we have it in Windows XP. However, you can try printing the
>   Device Resources by getting into System Properties. Here is the step
>   to get into System Properties.
>
> Click on Start, type **msinfo32** in the search box.
>
> 1. On the System Properties window, it will list the below options.
>
>    - Hardware Resources.
>    - Components.
>    - Software Environment.
>    - Select the option which you want to print.
>
> Now, select the **File** option from the Menu Bar, then click on **Export**
>   and then give a file name and select it.
>
> 2. Try opening the file and then print it.

Also you can list all devices with this PowerShell onliner (no tree, though):

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | Select Name, DeviceID
```

Example output:

```
Name                                                                                       DeviceID                                                                                 
----                                                                                       --------                                                                                 
Generic PnP Monitor                                                                        DISPLAY\NEC66C0\5&3A115792&2&UID257                                                      
Motherboard resources                                                                      ACPI\PNP0C02\1                                                                           
Motherboard resources                                                                      ACPI\PNP0C02\2                                                                           
Intel(R) processor DRAM Controller - 0044                                                  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0044&SUBSYS_1C771043&REV_18\3&11583659&0&00                             
Numeric data processor                                                                     ACPI\PNP0C04\4&142DD991&0                                                                
Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery                                            ACPI\PNP0C0A\0                                                                           
High Definition Audio Bus                                                                  PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_AA68&SUBSYS_AA681043&REV_00\4&179FD7D4&0&0108                           
Generic volume                                                                             STORAGE\VOLUME\{5200DD0F-4FFD-11E5-8381-806E6F6E6963}#0000001900100000                   
Root Print Queue                                                                           SWD\PRINTENUM\PRINTQUEUES                                                                
Volume Manager                                                                             ROOT\VOLMGR\0000                                                                         
Logicool USB (RX250) Optical Mouse                                                         USB\VID_046D&PID_C050\6&2582BEDF&0&2                                                     
Intel(R) 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 - 3B42                PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B42&SUBSYS_1C771043&REV_06\3&11583659&0&E0
```

Comment: +1 for the Powershell command.  You can do Invoke-Command -ComputerName hostname { Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | Select Name, DeviceID } to get a device list for a remote computer.

Answer (score 3):

Do this for Windows10:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost { Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | Where { $_.PNPClass -notin  "System","Net","Processor","SoftwareDevice","AudioEndpoint","BluetoothVirtual","Battery","Media","Volume","Modem","Camera","VolumeSnapshot","DiskDrive","Computer","HIDClass"}} | Sort-Object -Property PNPClass | Format-Table Name, Manufacturer, PNPClass, Status
```

Complete list of properties: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-pnpentity

[image]

Comment: Why "Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost"? Why not just calling Get-WmiObject directly?

Comment: @MehrdadMirreza, thank you, I posted that in case someone wanted to target a remote machine