# block/unblock usb devices except whitelist

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

If I want to block/unblock USB devices, I run in cmd:

```
:block
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\USBSTOR" /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f
:unblock
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\USBSTOR" /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f
```

What I want is:

1. generates a whitelist of connected usb devices (any usb, includes keyboard, usb storage, mouse, etc). (solved with **wmic path Win32_USBControllerDevice get * > usb.txt**)
2. lock/unlock all usb devices, except whitelist. In linux can be done with udev. I have no idea how it is done in Windows.

**Note**: Please. I prefer to use batch/wmic/regedit/cmd etc, instead [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) or other GUI solution. I'm also not interested in solutions based on Powershell

**My Research to solve the problem**:
I found a [colection of scripts based Devcon](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/devcon.php). There is one called [RenewUSB.bat](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/renewusb_2k.txt). This script remove all USB devices and then rescan for new ones. It could eventually serve as a starting point for what I want.

To download devcon in this [Microsoft Old link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150219111411/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272?). To obtain list drivers for all USB devices with commands:

```
%windir%\system32\devcon.exe DriverFiles =USB > usb.txt
%windir%\system32\devcon.exe find USB\* > usb.txt
%windir%\system32\devcon.exe find *VID* > usb.txt
```

PD: Most usb have the identifier "VID" and "USB". Example:

```
USB\VID_1C4F&PID_0002&MI_01\6&1578F7C2&0&0001 : Input device USB
HID\VID_1C4F&PID_0002&MI_00\7&2B89365C&0&0000 : Keyboard device HID
```

To block/unblock (specific device of usb.txt):

```
USB\VID_13FE&PID_1D00\5B7912980144     : USB storage device
%windir%\system32\devcon.exe disable *VID_13FE*
%windir%\system32\devcon.exe enable *VID_13FE*
```

To block/unblock all usb devices

```
%windir%\system32\devcon.exe disable *VID* *USB*
%windir%\system32\devcon.exe enable *VID* *USB*
```

Sometimes devcon does not disable all usb. Only a few. Example:

```
USB\VID_1C4F&PID_0002&MI_01\6&1578F7C2&0&0001 : Disabled
HID\VID_1C4F&PID_0002&MI_00\7&2B89365C&0&0000 : Disable failed
```

In this case, no solution. Only replace the command "disable" by "remove".

```
%windir%\system32\devcon.exe remove *VID* *USB*
```

But devcon is not a permanent solution for locking and unlocking devices (like reg add which it is). The test is that we can lock a usb device and then run bash script [renewusb_2k.bat](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/renewusb_2k.txt), and we will see that the script reinstall the usb drivers again and the locked usb device becomes accessible again. So devcon is not the solution to my request.

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

There are already [solutions that do this](https://www.maravento.com/2019/06/automatizando-reglas-gpo.html). You can vote to close this question

Comment: This can be done with a group policy.  Before I submit an answer, which will take me over an hour to write, what does your research indicate?

Comment: As I said in the question. I know how to do it in linux (bash), but I do not know how to do it in windows (batch). That is why I am asking.

Comment: http://m.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/authentication_and_encryption/Control-USB-Devices-Group-Policy.html Just use the enable GP instead of deny and then block all USB storage devices allow will become an exception to the deny policy

Comment: I am Asking for you to show us your research

Comment: My research has not worked. I appreciate your suggestion, but as I said in the question. I prefer batch/regedit/cmd

Comment: Well your idea how you go about it, won't work, the whitelist and blacklist has to be generated by hand.  You can allow "all" of a specific device type/etc (I.e all Dell mice) but without your research I can't help.   If you change your mind I got an answer half-written already

Comment: Remember that I request two things. Maybe if you can not help with the second, maybe with the first (generate the list of connected devices). I read that with wmic can get the list...

Comment: I've used [DevCon](http://ccm.net/faq/1886-enable-disable-a-device-from-the-command-line) but I do not think it works on all versions of windows and it's not very functional.

Comment: Solved request 1 (generates a whitelist of connected usb devices): wmic path Win32_USBControllerDevice get * > usb.txt

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because There are already solutions that do this

Answer (score 1):

See the following technet articles on how to restrict and allow devices via group policy. Specifically the `Prevent installation of devices not described by other policy settings` policy and the `Allow installation of devices that match any of these device IDs` policy. You'll need to generate a list of all devices, not just USB devices. Because I am unsure if the policy prevents new installs or will prevent existing installed devices from having their drivers loaded. Even if it was just new installs, consider that installing new drivers would count as new hardware being installed.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.06.grouppolicy.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772161(v=ws.10).aspx

If you insist on using the command line, you can create group policy objects with powershell:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461027.aspx

And to get a list of all devices presently installed on your system using powershell see this answer

[Powershell Script to Export all Devices in Device Manager as tree or list?](https://superuser.com/questions/1014635/powershell-script-to-export-all-devices-in-device-manager-as-tree-or-list)

AFAIK you can not do so using the legacy microsoft command prompt/batch files. You should switch over to powershell anyways as MS has disabled the legacy command prompt by default in the latest Windows 10 insider build and will likely make this change to all users in the next major update.

Comment: Cmd has not been removed from Windows 10. Only its access. [Can be reset again](http://www.solvetic.com/uploads/monthly_11_2016/tutorials-1-0-05236800-1480331700.jpg). And if it were completely eliminated, that's no problem. You can put the executable again in the path

Comment: "MS has disabled the legacy command prompt" - No it hasn't.  They spend hundreds of programming hours to add features to the command prompt with Windows 10 they are not going to disable it.

Comment: You can clearly see in the screenshot bdc posted it was disabled.

Comment: @MuhFugen No, the option translates to "Replace Command Prompt with Windows PowerShell in the menu when I right-click the start button or press Windows logo key + X".

Comment: Seems no one of you read the complete sentence as in "... legacy command prompt by default **in the latest Windows 10 insider build** ...AND"